# How can a poem be defined?

Tags: meaning, poetry

Merriam webster says:

> A piece of writing that usually has figurative language and that is written in separate lines that often have a repeated rhythm and sometimes rhyme.

Googling 'define: poem' gives :

> A piece of writing that partakes of the nature of both speech and song that is nearly always rhythmical, usually metaphorical, and often exhibits such formal elements as meter, rhyme, and stanzaic structure.

What are the essential constituents of a poem?

Going by the above definitions, a poem MUST be a piece of writing, written is separate lines that partakes of the nature of both speech and song.

Comment: *Poem* and *poetry* can be (and have been) defined a thousand different ways; every poem constitutes a redefinition of the term. What do you want to do with your definition?

Comment: I thought there would (or should) be a standard or rather formal definition. It appears few poems adhere to formal elements of poetry (meter, rhyme, etc.) today. So, there should be a clear distinction between a piece of writing and a poem.

Comment: *A poem is composition of words that adheres to the prosodic rules of its particular genre.*  The next questions would be, what are the various poetic genres? How does this poetic genre differ from that poetic genre? What, if anything, do *all* poetic genres have in common that separates them from other compositions of words that are not members of any poetic genre? I don't know if one could get very far with the last question.

Comment: Japanese haiku  in some other languages  might not be poems.

Comment: One of the most obvious shortcomings for every definition I see created or cited on this page is they all say a poem is a ***written*** composition. I have no doubt linguistic communities with no written language were and are quite capable of producing poems, and accurately passing them on to others ***verbally***.

Comment: I've heard one chapter of Tolkien's 'The Lord of the Rings" be claimed to be a single poem. It seems to fulfil none of the above requirements (a piece of writing that usually has figurative language and that is written in separate lines that often have a repeated rhythm and sometimes rhyme), but prosaic it is not.

Comment: Why should there be a "clear distinction"? Any utterance (which need not even be linguistic - many musical works are called 'tone poems') which is read in the light of other works the reader takes to be poems is by that act constituted a poem.

Answer (score 1):

In very broad terms, writing can be divided into *poetry* and *prose*. Prose is common or everyday language, while poetry is an **art form**. Poems use language features to engage the audience's imagination and evoke an emotional response.

Definition of [poetry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poetry) from Merriam-Webster:

> writing that formulates a concentrated **imaginative awareness** of experience in language chosen and arranged to create a **specific emotional response** through **meaning**, **sound**, and **rhythm** (emphasis added)

And the definition of [prose](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prose):

> a :  the **ordinary language** people use in speaking or writing (emphasis added)
>
> b :  a literary medium distinguished from poetry especially by its greater irregularity and variety of rhythm and its closer correspondence to the patterns of **everyday speech** (emphasis added)

Poems have many potential elements, forms, and genres. Some modern poetry omits many of the traditional poetic features (meter, rhythm, rhyme, etc.) and blurs the distinction between poetry and prose.

I don't think it is possible to define the "essential constituents of a (generic) poem" any more than it is possible to define the "essential elements of art". However, that may be possible for specific forms or genres of poems. For example, [haiku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetry#Haiku) uses a well-defined syllabic structure.

Answer (score 0):

A small work of art with words as found in any collection of poetry.
There are hundreds of metric forms, and hundreds of topics and intensions.
There are even poems in prose. Even a small Japanese haiku I would see as a poem.

But actually everybody knows what a poem is so such definitions are dull and mere academic exercises, but who will read such definitions.